# how to use mysql rewriter plugin?

Tags: mysql, plugins

I am trying to use mysql default rewrite plugin as per their instructions but it is giving me some grief. Simply put after activating rules the plugin is simply not working.

Below is my table and rules but simply queries are not reporting correct results. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
mysql> select creditcard_number from mihir_test.creditcard_info where name = "mihir";
+-------------------+
| creditcard_number |
+-------------------+
| 1234567890123456  |
+-------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into query_rewrite.rewrite_rules ( pattern, replacement) values ( 'select creditcard_number from mihir_test.creditcard_info where name = ?', 'select name, creditcart_number from mihir_test.creditcard_info where name = ?' );
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> CALL query_rewrite.flush_rewrite_rules();
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> select creditcard_number from mihir_test.creditcard_info where name = "mihir";                                                                                            +-------------------+
| creditcard_number |
+-------------------+
| 1234567890123456  |
+-------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: What results do yo need?

Comment: I was hoping that query would be translated and it would give me name and creditcard_number both as a result. I don't understand What went wrong? Thanks.